# pyspark: how to partition by date column in format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH'

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I have tried the following:

```
df = (spark.createDataFrame([(1, '2020-12-03 01:01:01'), (2, '2022-11-04 10:10:10'),], ['id', 'txt'])
  .withColumn("testCol", to_timestamp(col("txt"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH")))
```

[image: result]

I basically want a timestamp/datetime column in the format (yyyy-MM-dd HH). The above piece of code gives the following result as shown in image. But when I try to write this to Azure Blob Storage partitioned by this time column then it gives some garbage like:

[image: final result]

Is there any cleaner way to do this such that the column format remains timestamp/datetime in the format (yyyy-MM-dd HH) and at same time while writing the partition it looks clean in the same way and not the garbage strings of '%3A55%....'

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `date_format`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, '2020-12-03 01:01:01'), (2, '2022-11-04 10:10:10')],
    ['id', 'txt']
)
df = df.withColumn("testCol", F.col("txt").cast("timestamp"))
df.withColumn("testCol", F.date_format("txt", "yyyy-MM-dd HH")).write.partitionBy('testCol').csv('output')

df.show()
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|                txt|            testCol|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|2020-12-03 01:01:01|2020-12-03 01:01:01|
|  2|2022-11-04 10:10:10|2022-11-04 10:10:10|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- txt: string (nullable = true)
 |-- testCol: timestamp (nullable = true)

$ ls output
_SUCCESS  testCol=2020-12-03 01  testCol=2022-11-04 10
```

Comment: but here the testCol column is of typoe string. I want to keep the type as timestamp/datetime

Comment: @user3868051 datetimes cannot be formatted unless they are converted to a string

Comment: @user3868051 I have added a line to convert the column `txt` to timestamp type. So there are now two columns, one of timestamp type (`txt`), another of string type which is a formatted timestamp (`testCol`). Do you still want anything else?

Comment: yes, I want 'testCol' column as timestamp/datetime and use the same for partitioning correctly. I do not want to use its format as 'string'. That is the issue I am having

Comment: @user3868051 I have edited my answer - the column can be formatted before the `write` operation, which will not affect the dataframe. Does that address your needs?

Comment: no, as per your answer the format of testcol is correct but it is still a string. When you do df.write.partitionby() step I want to pass this testCol column like you have except that this column needs to be a timestamp/datetime... not STRING.

Comment: `testcol` is only a string when it is passed to partitionby. it remains a timestamp in the original dataframe df, as shown in the result of `df.show()`. Does that clarify any misunderstanding...?

Comment: Note that `df.withColumn(...)` does not modify `df`. I have added the schema for your reference @user3868051

Comment: @user3868051 I do not understand why you insist on passing a timestamp column to partitionby. Passing a string column works equally well, and provides more flexibility with formatting. Also it is impossible to format a timestamp according to your needs, if you pass a timestamp column to partitionby.

Comment: how is date_format() returning timestamp for you? It returns a stringtype column for me https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html which does not work for my requirement.

Comment: thanks will probably use as stringtype only for now then.